# Understand AXML format especially AndroidManifest one

Tags: android, format, reverse

I'm currently working on an AXML format file. As you're probably aware, Android has its own XML format. You can find an example by extracting an APK and locating XML files in the "res" directory or the "AndroidManifest.xml" file.
You might have encountered issues when trying to modify these AXML files, which is why I'm creating my own library to make on-the-fly patches.
The project works quite well; you can try it out here: https://gitlab.com/MadSquirrels/mobile/androidmanifest
However, an error persists. It appears that the AndroidManifest has a unique interpretation of the AXML format, leading to errors during APK installation.
It seem that it find tags as name but it’s not recognized as android manifest tag name.
I encourage you to test this project. Its aim is to be open source, and if you manage to solve this issue, I'm not sure how I could adequately express my gratitude, but I'd definitely credit you in the project.
Feel free to share any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fix my problem, I forgot to implement a section with ids of generic attributes. I release the project here https://pypi.org/project/pyaxml/ for anyone who need to manipulate AXML.